# How do I get rid of the ActiveX warning in a VB.NET application using the WebBrowser control?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

We have a VB.Net app that has several editable reports and forms in html/javascript. I'm using the standard WebBrowser control.

We're accessing the content via filepath, since using \localhost\sharename when the machine is offline doesn't work even though the content is on the machine. The problem with that is that then it's running in the local machine zone, and you get the warning about running ActiveX controls (even if that's set to 'allow' in the options menu on IE).

So I'm using Mark of the Web to act as if the content is saved from localhost. I appended it with the requisite vbCrLf to the start of the HTML page that's being dynamically written every time a link is clicked. When I open the resulting page in IE, I no longer get the ActiveX warning, and everything works. However, when I use WebBrowser.Navigate to that filepath, I still get the warning. Any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: Running activeX controls is unsafe. Don't trick the users into running it without a warning. (Also activeX is evil!)

Comment: the page includes javascript, and we don't have the option of rewriting the web content.

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try by Setting the property ScriptErrorsSuppressed of webbrowser to true, i think that will solve you problem.

Comment: that does suppress the error popup successfully, but it doesn't allow the scripts to run. it's the same as clicking 'no' in the dialog.